Design rules for in-case strain relief clip placement
I have a project that I am designing a plastic enclosure for. (While the prototypes will be  most likely 3D printed through a vendor, I am baking injection molding DFM into the design so that I don't wind up with something that's going to cause future-me to throw a fit if it does wind up going to production.)
In this project, the wiring enters as 3 individual leads (18AWG TFFN, to be precise) through a simple hole in the back of the case, then pass through a strain-relief clip integral to the case back before heading up to the board, where they are further strain-relieved to the board by being woven through retention holes in the board before being soldered down to it.
The problem, though, is I can't find for the life of me any sort of rule of thumb to guide me in placing and orienting that clip with respect to the entry hole for the wires, given that I cannot place the clip much more than 50mm away from the hole in question?
I have been trying to apply guidance material based on a constant wire bending radius (minimum bend radius for 18AWG TFFN ranges from 11 to about 14 mm, using the "5X" rule from the NEC for single conductor cables), but that produces a geometry that "balloons" out into where the board goes, and conflicts with the examples I have seen of sharply trained conductors in equipment.  Or is there some other logic I should be using instead...?

Does the wire repeatedly flex when your product is being used? If yes, you need a rubber boot, so all the stress isn't at the exit point.

Other logic- look at something similar, and adapt or copy it if it works. Or 3D print your bespoke design on your desktop and iterate as required. 3D printing is different from injection molding in important ways, especially material quality, tolerances and surface finish and things to do with how the mold opens (undercuts that require slides and such like, crossovers etc.), gate placement, parting line design and heat transfer/shrinkage considerations (start with constant wall thickness where possible, but there are many other details).

@Mattman944 -- the product doesn't move during normal operation, no

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany -- basically, i'm baking in concerns about not needing undercuts and the like + draft angles for mold parting as well as keeping walls thin enough that shrinkage isn't a massive concern

Sharp bends will create a weak point. But, if you don't have movement, the weak point is less likely to cause issues. You may be overthinking this.

The path the cord follows in my Logitech trackball is a good example of a well-designed  strain relief. The cords eventually fail but not near the unit and they never put any force on the internal 2mm connector.
